# Differences in global variable declarations in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, class, dart, static, declaration

I am trying to figure out the best practices on how to write Dart. The thing that really confuses me at the moment is how different types of declarations are possible. So one thing I am clear about is that I should avoid declaring classes with only static members, just because I want to have classes, referring [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members).

Let's say I want to create a simple navigation service, where I can call methods like `navigate` and `pop`. As far as I know, I can declare this in 4 main different ways:

1)

```
class NavigationService {
  static final NavigationService _instance = NavigationService._();
  NavigationService._();

  factory NavigationService() => _instance;

  void navigate() {}
  void pop() {}
}
```

2. 

```
class NavigationService {
  NavigationService();

  void navigate() {}
  void pop() {}
}
```

3. 

```
class NavigationService {
  NavigationService();

  static void navigate() {}
  static void pop() {}
}
```

4. 

```
void navigate() {}
void pop() {}
```

- In this example, which one should I go for and why?
- Also what would be a use case for the other declarations?

Comment: 1, 3 and 4 are functionally equivalent, so wouldn't you go with the one that is syntactically simplest? 2 is just a regular class with methods, of which there can be more than one instance.

Comment: of course I would, I am just trying to understand what if there are any differences between them. I get the obvious difference with 2. though. So there is actually no difference between 1 and 3 at all? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: 1 is a singleton so any non-static methods operate on the instance, of which there is only one. 3 is a regular class with static methods. If those are the only methods, which are in a class simply to be in a class, the Dart community prefers the fourth method. In 1 you are simply using the singleton to make those methods essentially static and therefore equivalent to 3.

Comment: Okay got it, thank you very much. One last question, if I had a variable inside this 'class', a variable that never changes, like `final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();` for instance. Which declaration would be preferred here? Would I still go for the 4th one? I am just trying to understand if classes have any use cases here

Comment: If you made your methods using (4) you'd likely make it a top-level variable. (You could prefix it with `_` if it was only to be used 'locally'.)

Comment: @RichardHeap one more thing I am curious about, would there actually be a good way to mock such global declarations? How would you go about widget testing with them?